# C++ opengl fragment shader not filling the screen with white

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

So basically I tried to fill the whole screen with white using the fragment shader, however it does not seem to work.
P.S.- Im new to programming shaders in c++, I have done so sucessfully in java so its not like I dont understand anything, but its not like I understand everything either.
P.S.S. Sorry for bad english.

main.cpp

```
#include<glad/glad.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "main.h"
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

static const GLchar* readFromFile(const GLchar* pathToFile)
{
    std::string content;
    std::ifstream fileStream(pathToFile, std::ios::in);

    if (!fileStream.is_open()) {
        std::cerr << "Could not read file " << pathToFile << ". File does not exist." << std::endl;
        return "";
    }

    std::string line = "";
    while (!fileStream.eof()) {
        std::getline(fileStream, line);
        content.append(line + "\n");
    }

    fileStream.close();
    std::cout << content << std::endl;
    return content.c_str();
}


static void processInput(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ENTER && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glClearColor(1.06666666666667f, 0.168888888888889f, 0.306666666666667f, 1.0f);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    const char* vertexShaderSource = readFromFile("vertex.glsl");
    const char* fragmentShaderSource = readFromFile("frag.glsl");

    //initialize GLFW
    glfwInit();

    //tell GLFW the openGl version
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 1);

    //tell GLFW that we will use the core profile
    //witch means that we will only use the modern funcions and dont neeed the old ones
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    //create a window
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 800, "GLFW", NULL, NULL);
    //check if we created a widow succesfully
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    //set the created window as the current context
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    //tell glad to configure openGL
    gladLoadGL();

    //set the viewport to go from x = 0, y = 0 (bottom left corner) to x = 800, y = 800 (top right corner)
    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 800);

    // vertex shader
    GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);


    // fragment shader
    GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);

    //create references to the vertex array object, vertex buffer object and the element array buffer
    GLuint VAO, VBO, EBO;
    
    //generate them
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    
    //bind them
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    //configure the vertex attribute 
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    //enable it
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    //unbind not needed VBO's, VAO's and the EBO's
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    //specify the clear color and clean the back buffer
    glClearColor(0.07f, 0.13f, 0.17f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //swap the buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, processInput);

    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    //dispose of all the stuff we made
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

    //return the exit code 0 = succesfull
    return 0;
}
```

Fragment shader

```
out vec4 gl_FragColor


void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
}
```

EDIT: So turns out i totally forgot that you have to draw something on the screen for the fragment shader to take effect. Thanks Rabbid76

Comment: You need to draw a rectangle over the entire viewport (window).

Comment: There are `VBO` and `EBO` but you don't generate them nor fill them.